# Place finder android app in which users can upload places to the sever?

Tags: android, mysql, google-places-api

I am wondered if any one knows a source code(free or Licensed) about any **place finding android studio project** with in which the users are able to create and upload their own created places to the server?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clear but anyway

this is a library that could help you work with the Places API 
https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java

and this is a project that implemented the places API 
https://github.com/pradeepms/Google-places-API